# W3C Geolocation API extremely inaccurate

Tags: geolocation, w3c-geolocation

I'm using the W3C geolocation api in my new webproject.
When I'm somewhere in or near a bigger city, the api works perfectly! :)

Problem is:
Here at home, a smaller city with about 5000 inhabitants, it's EXTREMELY inaccurate.
I mean .. in my opinion 5k isn't that small. Plus: I'm logged in via WiFi, so it should be at least close to my location.

But when I use it on my laptop while logged into my WiFi here, the api places me about 140 km (!!!) away from my right location. That's absolutely unacceptable for my new webapp.

Does anyone of you have any idea why it is that inaccurate?

best regards
P

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of the API depends on the client. Most mobile phones will use their built in GPS to determine the location. Web browsers on a laptop don't have that option so will fallback to alternatives. Looks like your browser is using a GeoIP database.